# Android libVLC - file path instead of URL error

Tags: android, libvlc, vlc-android

I am usign Gary example from [here](https://github.com/gareoke/VLCPlayer).

The only modify is  that I load a local video like this:

```
    mMediaUrl = "/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4";
```

and I get the following error:

```
10-03 12:54:13.588 16681-17397/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: Warning: input_item_SetURI("/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4"): file path instead of URL.
10-03 12:54:13.588 16681-17397/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC-std: input_SplitMRL("/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4") probably not a valid URI!
10-03 12:54:15.718 16681-17399/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC: [dece4214] core input: open of `/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4' failed
10-03 12:54:15.728 16681-17399/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC: [dece4214] core input: Your input can't be opened
10-03 12:54:15.728 16681-17399/windylabs.com.vlcplayersample E/VLC: [dece4214] core input: VLC is unable to open the MRL '/storage/emulated/0/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4'. Check the log for details.
```

I don't know where the logs specified on the error are. The example, with the video streamed from [here](http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4) it is working, but the video from my sdcard isn't played!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solutin, maybe wil help someone, sometime.

You need to load file like this:

```
mMediaUrl = Uri.fromFile(pathToMediaFile).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mMediaUrl = "/sdcard/MyFolder/20161003_1217.mp4";
```

or check `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in manifest.